# How to format "cloud_auth" in logstash pipeline output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elastic-cloud

I'm running logstash 7.12.1, and the pipeline I'm trying to run will not accept my cloud_auth syntax for some reason. It hits an error right after the " that contains the user:password pair. I've triple checked the documentation below and can't find the problem.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.12/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-cloud_auth

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.12/connecting-to-cloud.html

[ERROR][Converge PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "{", "}" at line 15, column 20 after output {\n  elasticsearch { \n    cloud_id => "cluster:djMWUw\n    cloud_auth => "", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in` initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in` initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389:in` block in converge_state'"]}

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    cloud_id => "cluster:dXM2VzdEu2NLNs3VkmVLlv5MMQMVOQ5NjiGyafdsg63DFH67M2JhNzlhOTZmOTNjJDM5ZWYyZWNiYzQ2NTliNWM4ZESTGARFHhsrtghsdfMWUw
    cloud_auth => "elastic:lpertgAFHJYTNzWFvR2aH"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a double quote at the end of cloud_id.